# Not able to access form elements properly in ruby on rails.

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, search, form-submit

I am developing a rails app. I have a issue with the form submission and rendering. 
Here is the code for "show" view.

```
  <%= form_for :search_form do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_field :search_tag %><br>
    <%= f.submit "find" %>
    <% end %>
  <% @array_bookmark = @bookmark.class == Array ? @bookmark : [@bookmark] %>
  <% @array_bookmark.each do |book| %>
  <li><%= book.url%>
  <b>Title:</b>
  <li><%= book.title%>
  <% end %>
```

And the controller action is :

```
def show
  if request.post?
  @bookmark = Bookmark.new(params[:search_form])

  bookmark = Bookmark.find_by_title(@bookmark.search_tag)
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # index.html.erb
    format.json { render json: @bookmark }
  end
  end  
end
```

The view is the search form , when the form is submitted , it goes to controller and search for the element entered in the database and yield it back to the same view , where it is displayed.
How can i do it? Please provide me a solution.

Answer (score 0):

The first result of a google search for 'rails search example' is https://we.riseup.net/rails/simple-search-tutorial

I'd recommend you spend some time reading rails documentation.  Start here http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html

Also notice the form_for helper is for creating a form around a particular model http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_for. if you are creating some random custom form the helper you want is form_tag http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-form_tag.

Also, usually the show view is meant to display an individual resource.  The index view is meant to display a collection of resources.  Of course these are just conventions, not rules, but I would suggest that your code violates the conventions here.